# Concurrent Connections

Tags: windows-7, windows, internet, connection

How can you see how much concurrent connects you can handle? I use windows 7 and I have read the licensing term and it said Windows 7 has a limit of 20. But, when I got the Half-open limit fix, it said I have no limit. I don't know how I have no limit because I have never played around with anything pertaining that that.

So can anyone tell me a way of testing how many concurrent connections I can handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this answer](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7performance/thread/91496c0e-ce0c-4c30-9995-798625de0918) Windows 7 does not have a connection limit anymore. The same is true for Windows Vista with SP2.

[Here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/06/07/half-open-outbound-tcp-connections-limit-removed-in-windows-7-and-vista-sp2-no-patch-required/) is a bit more about the topic.

Comment: Ty ty. Btw, if you don't me piggy backing my own question, can your isp also limit your connection?

Comment: Don't know about that although I doubt it. Some could enforce bandwidth cap though. Depends on ISP I guess and on how heavy the traffic is on your connection, both outgoing and incoming.

Comment: Yes they can set the modem's maximum concurrent connections

Comment: Your second link is talking about partial TCP/IP connections, not about how many other machines may access a Windows computer!

Answer (score 1):

The half-open connections limit is different from the limit imposed by licensing.  The one in the license refers to the number of remote users accessing your computer, for instance, printing to a shared printer or accessing your Shared Files folder.