# How to prove maximum concurrent connections limit in windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, tcpip

We need to verify that our clients (Windows Vista SP 2 and Windows 7) are able to open more than 10/20 connections.

I found [an answer which states the limit was removed](https://superuser.com/a/185510/224737), but without any source like MSDN or the use of a windows utility.

Is there any trustable source to verify this statement?

Comment: Do you mean TCP/IP connections or other connections? Because Windows never had a hard TCP connection limit (you could of course run out of resources, but that took thousands of connections depending on your PC)

Comment: That answer is actually talking about TCP/IP connections, not about accessing Windows.  Something like 2 years ago I hit the limit on both Windows 7 and 8.  SQL Express was fine for what we were doing--until they added too many machines and Windows wouldn't let them in.

Answer (score 2):

**Windows 7** Type `winver` in the start menu, click on the *Microsoft Software License Terms* and go to section 3F

[image]

Vista home limit is 5 and the others are 10 -

[image]

[source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdocuments%2Fuseterms%2FWindows%2520Vista_Ultimate_English_36d0fe99-75e4-4875-8153-889cf5105718.pdf&ei=PhQtVKzDE4i5ggTG44KwAQ&usg=AFQjCNEBRLOQMNJXvQwPAr0BjLMLct5jCw&sig2=9nMuddy6LWTdU877If4q1A)

Comment: "The software" means Windows though, not a server program someone else wrote.

Answer (score 0):

" net config server"

Will give you something like this:

```
Server hidden                         No
Maximum Logged On Users               20
Maximum open files per session        16384

Idle session time (min)               15
The command completed successfully.
```